# vegas.js plugin not working with overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vegasjs

Recently I came across **vegas.js** plugin
  not sure how to use it...  Read the documentation but did not get a clear idea. http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/setup/ 
    Did the steps accordingly but no images are showing.

```
  <script>
    $.vegas('slideshow', {
      backgrounds:[
        { src:'img/F1.jpg', fade:1000 },
        { src:'img/f2.jpeg', fade:1000 },

      ]
    })('overlay', {
      src:'/vegas/overlays/11.png'
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using firebug/inspector, click on console, and paste in what is going on. There will be errors in there. Also could you post how you're including the file? Post with your html if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As you can se in the [settings section](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/settings/) the overlay property goes inside of the vegas function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imagecollection = [{
      src: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png'
    },
    {
      src: 'http://i.imgur.com/SZPjHwz.jpg'
    },
    {
      src: 'http://www.boyter.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ChJzv9lUYAA9D5E.jpg'
    },
    {
      src: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cg0x8vnXEAEB2Le.jpg'
    }
    /* Slideshow not working? Check your image links. */
  ];

  $("#ShowSlideShowHere").vegas({
    slides: imagecollection,
    transition: 'fade',
    preloadImage: true,
    timer: true,
    shuffle: true,
    delay: 5000,
    animation: 'kenburns',
    cover: true,
    overlay: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/isolated-christmas-falling-snow-overlay-on-transparent-background-vector-id628152000'
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.0/vegas.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.0/vegas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height:100vh">
    <div id="ShowSlideShowHere" style="height:100vh">sadasdasdas</div>
  </div>
```